# How to change "2022-05-13T17:02:34Z" string to a millisecondsSinceEpoch in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to compare two dates and times and get the event that occurred first. 1) 1652459529384 2) 2022-05-13T17:02:34Z

How can I change 2022-05-13T17:02:34Z to this millisecondsSinceEpoch ?
Or How can I compare the two times in flutter?

Comment: Once you convert the string to a `DateTime` object, you can use its [`compareTo`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html), [`isBefore`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html), or [`isAfter`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/isAfter.html) methods to compare it to another `DateTime`, or use its [`millisecondsSinceEpoch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html) getter.

Comment: Thanks alot James, Your idea will help me much